# Doctrine2 and magic finders with more fields not working?

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Doctrine2 allows you to query using magic finders based on field names. If you have an entity named `User` you should able to call `$repo->findOneByUsernameAndPassword()` assuming that the entity has username and password fields.

***How can i pass parameters to magic finders? How to query when the field that is actually a relation?***

I've tried:

```
$repo->findOneByUsernameAndPassword('Jhon', 'password')
```

and

```
$repo->findOneByUsernameAndPassword(array('Jhon', 'password'))
```

but i'm getting the error:

> Entity 'User' has no field 'usernameAndPassword'. You can therefore
>   not call 'findOneByUsernameAndPassword'

Comment: This is possible with doctrine 1. Where did you read it was possible with doctrine 2?

Comment: Can't remember. Maybe i'm wrong? If you are sure then answer this question, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any reference for this syntax with Doctrine 2, though it was possible with Doctrine 1. I used it myself then and remember having problems getting it to work.
Now you would rather do this I guess :

```
$repo->findOneBy(array('username' => 'Jhon', 'password' => 'password'));
```

You can get more information in [this § of the Doctrine 2 documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

Comment: Thank you. I find strange that such a good feature has been removed. Anyway this is an alternative way to keep the code clean: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes